# awk To Generate Sequence Numbers based on Start and End Range:

Tags: awk

Would like to generate Generate Sequence Numbers based on Start and End Range along with description.

Input.txt

```
SatrtRange,EndRange,Date, Desc
5,10,20-Jun-2014,abc
20,25,30-Jun-2014,def
2,2,15-May-2014,ghi
```

Have tried below command and got partial output:

```
awk -F, '{s[NR]=$1;e[NR]=$2;} { for (i=s[NR];i<=e[NR];i++) print i} ' Input.txt >Op_Con_Seq_Num.txt
```

Output:

```
5
6
7
8
9
10
20
21
22
23
24
25
2
```

However, want to print other fields info as well from Input.txt , please suggest ..

Desired Output:

```
5,20-Jun-2014,abc
6,20-Jun-2014,abc
7,20-Jun-2014,abc
8,20-Jun-2014,abc
9,20-Jun-2014,abc
10,20-Jun-2014,abc
20,30-Jun-2014,def
21,30-Jun-2014,def
22,30-Jun-2014,def
23,30-Jun-2014,def
24,30-Jun-2014,def
25,30-Jun-2014,def
2,15-May-2014,ghi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close:

```
awk -F, '{s[NR]=$1;e[NR]=$2;} { for (i=s[NR];i<=e[NR];i++) print i","$3","$4} ' Input.txt
```

Comment: While this will produce the output you want it's not a good solution as there's no need for arrays, no need for separate blocks, and no need to hard-code an OFS in the print.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=$1;i<=$2;i++) print i,$3,$4}' Input.txt
```